# Is tensorflow lite model already quantized?

Tags: tensorflow, quantization, tensorflow-lite

Does the converted tensorflow lite model always have quantized calculation and output?
Or it depends on the tensorflow model's input and inference type?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It depends on the inference type.

First the input model should be instrumented with quantization operations, https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/tree/master/tensorflow/contrib/quantize can be helpful with that.

The resulting eval graph should be provided to TOCO for conversion with --inference_type=QUANTIZED_UINT8 and the correct --mean_values and --std_values for the input arrays.

See https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/master/tensorflow/contrib/lite/toco/g3doc/cmdline_examples.md for some examples of how to invoke TOCO for quantized models.

UPDATE: We have added a new post training quantization tool: https://medium.com/tensorflow/tensorflow-model-optimization-toolkit-post-training-integer-quantization-b4964a1ea9ba that should be easier than the old methods of quantization.

Comment: How to estimate `mean_values` and `std_values` ?